# Trying to pull specific values from a database

Tags: python, regex, database, sqlite

I have an sqlite3 table in python that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE words
              (ID                    INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY      AUTOINCREMENT,
               CURRENT_WORD          TEXT     NOT NULL,
               BEFORE_WORD           TEXT     NOT NULL,
               AFTER_WORD            TEXT     NOT NULL,
               OCCURANCES            INTEGER      NOT NULL)
```

It returns the following database values:

```
(1, u'is', u'This', u'true', 0)
(2, u'you', u'are', u'ready', 1)
```

I'd like to be able to pull the value 'OCCURANCES' from id 2. I've tried the following, I was then planning to parse the returned value with regex, but my code doesn't appear to be working:

```
def db_check(db, words):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    c = conn.cursor()
    frequency = 0
    print("SELECT * FROM words WHERE CURRENT_WORD = '" + words[1] + "' AND BEFORE_WORD = '" + words[0] + "' AND AFTER_WORD = '" + words[2] + "'")
    for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM words WHERE CURRENT_WORD = '" + words[1] + "' AND BEFORE_WORD = '" + words[0] + "' AND AFTER_WORD = '" + words[2] + "'"):
        print "FOUND: "
        print row
    conn.commit()
    if frequency == 0: frequency = 1
    return frequency
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong? I'd say it's wrong with my SQL in the last part. Is there a better way to do this, such as pulling the frequency exactly?

Comment: What is your input data (`words`) and what is the output of that function? I do not work with Python, but couldn't you do something like `row["OCCRANCES"]` or `row[4]` in order to pull `OCCURANCES` value?

Comment: This code looks OK (except that you should use SQL parameters, but that does not matter if the words don't contain quotes). The problem is with your data.